# ManyToMany Relation is updating the domain table

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

So I have a ManyToMany relation mapped this way:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinTable( name = "post_category",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "post_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    )
    private List<CategoryEntity> post_categories;
```

and then:

```
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "post_categories")
    private List<PostEntity> posts;
```

The relation is meant to be like this:
[image]

The thing is: I have posts that have categories and these categories are in a static table, which I don't want to change ever. I only want to change the relation table.
When I first save a Post it works, but when I try to update a post, it patches the table which should be static:
Method to update:

```
    public Post att(Post model, Integer id) throws ResponseStatusException {
        Optional<PostEntity> optionalEntity = repo.findById(id);

        if(!optionalEntity.isPresent()) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Post not found");
        }

        PostEntity entity = optionalEntity.get();
        entity.setPost_categories(((model.getPost_categories() != null) ? CategoryMapper.marshall(model.getPost_categories()) : entity.getPost_categories()));
        entity.setPost_author((model.getPost_author() != null) ? model.getPost_author() : entity.getPost_author());
        entity.setTitle((model.getTitle() != null) ? model.getTitle() : entity.getTitle());

        return PostMapper.unmarshall(repo.save(entity));    
    }
```

Is the relation ok? What am I doing wrong??

The github link of project is here, https://github.com/moreiravictor/EspatodeAPI/tree/master/src/main/java/br/com/espatodea/espatodeAPI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot I found out it was a problem with the cascadeType. So in order to solve this you only have to change to REFRESH:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinTable( name = "post_category",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "post_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    )
    private List<CategoryEntity> post_categories;
```

The REFRESH cascadeType allows you to only make change on the father of the relation. This way the child (categories) will never change.